# Call to Google Cloud API in Celery task never returns

Tags: python, flask, google-cloud-platform, celery

I am trying to make a call to a external `Google Cloud Natural Language API`
from within a `Celery` task (using the `google-cloud-python` package). The problem is that the call to the API never returns (hangs):

```
@celery.task()
def get_entities_async():
    return get_entities()

def get_entities():
    gcloud_client = LanguageServiceClient()
    doc = types.Document(content='This is a test.', language='en', type='PLAIN_TEXT')
    res = gcloud_client.analyze_entities(document=doc)  # This call never returns
    print('Call successful!')   # (This never gets printed)
    return res
```

What I've tried to solve problem:

- Calling the method `get_entities()` from a script. This works fine.
- Added a `timeout=1` and `retry=False` to the API call. It still hangs.
- Called the API using the `requests` module instead. This works fine with celery, so the problem has to be something within `LanguageServiceClient`.

Any ideas on how to debug or solve this problem?

Comment: Celery has a debugger, [`rdb`](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/reference/celery.contrib.rdb.html) that may help you investigate the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the problem seems to be in the `LanguageServiceClient`, I used the `requests` module instead to call the API inside the `celery` worker:

```
import requests

# Temporary solution to call the Natural Language API
def get_entities():
    doc = {'type': 1, 'language': 'en', 'content': 'This is a test.'}
    d = {'document': doc, 'encodingType': 'UTF32'}
    url = 'https://language.googleapis.com/v1beta2/documents:analyzeEntities?key=' + API_KEY
    return requests.post(url, json=d, timeout=10.0).json())
```

Comment: You might want to add an explicit timeout to your POST request to prevent it from potentially hanging indefinitely: `requests.post(url, json=d, timeout=1.0).json())`
(have a look at http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#timeouts)