# Calling API within Celery task never returns

Tags: python, flask, celery, web3py

I want to get a value from `web3.eth.getTransactionCount`. It just hangs. This function works fine elsewhere(normal app, console).

To recreate this behavior simply create a new folder, add these 3 files to the folder, and inside that folder run `docker-compose up`. *Note that infura credentials are safe to use.

dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.7
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
RUN pip install flask celery[redis] web3
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3"
services:
  redis:
    image: redis:5.0.7
    container_name: redis
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
  myapp:
    build: .
    container_name: myapp
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/app
    environment:
      - FLASK_ENV=development
      - WEB3_INFURA_PROJECT_ID=1cc71ab02b99475b8a3172b6a790c2f8
      - WEB3_INFURA_API_SECRET=6a343124ed8e4a6f9b36d28c50ad65ca
    entrypoint: |
      bash -c "python /usr/src/app/app.py"
  celery:
    build: .
    container_name: celery
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/app
    environment:
      - WEB3_INFURA_PROJECT_ID=1cc71ab02b99475b8a3172b6a790c2f8
      - WEB3_INFURA_API_SECRET=6a343124ed8e4a6f9b36d28c50ad65ca
    command: celery worker -A app.client -l info
```

app.py

```py
from flask import Flask
from web3.auto.infura.rinkeby import w3 as web3
from celery import Celery

app = Flask(__name__)
client = Celery(app.name, broker='redis://redis:6379', backend='redis://redis:6379')

@client.task
def never_return():
    print('start')  # this is printed
    nonce = web3.eth.getTransactionCount('0x51cDD4A883144F01Bf0753b6189f3A034866465f')
    print('nonce', nonce)  # this is never printed

@app.route('/')
def index():
    never_return.apply_async()
    return "hello celery"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0')
```

I found only 1 similar unresolved post here: [Call to Google Cloud API in Celery task never returns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51964541/call-to-google-cloud-api-in-celery-task-never-returns)

There seems to be something weird when making a request call by other library within Celery task. Everything works fine when I tried making post requests using `request`. Unfortunately I don't know how to work around this problem using this `request` library.

Any kind of suggestions are highly appreciated.

Comment: Is it recognized as celery task when you start celery? How do you call it? Are you using celery beat and schedule? Does it run in docker container?

Comment: Yes, celery console recognize the method and have successfully logged "start". Not using celery beat and schedule. Yes there are 3 containers: app, redis and celery.

Comment: You do not call print() inside Celery tasks... Use the Celery logger instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems to me this issue has something to do with websockets. so i tried to switch it to HTTP. and it works.

here is modified app.py

```py
from flask import Flask
from web3 import Web3
from celery import Celery
from web3.middleware import geth_poa_middleware
import os

app = Flask(__name__)
client = Celery(app.name, broker='redis://redis:6379', backend='redis://redis:6379')

@client.task
def never_return():
    w3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider(f"https://rinkeby.infura.io/v3/{os.getenv('WEB3_INFURA_PROJECT_ID')}", request_kwargs={'timeout': 60}))
    w3.middleware_onion.inject(geth_poa_middleware, layer=0)
    print('started')
    l = w3.eth.getBlock('latest')
    print(f'block number: {l}')
    print('finished ok')

@app.route('/')
def index():
    never_return.apply_async()
    return f"hello celery"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0')
```